# Get XML from PHP to Jquery - XML tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I am trying to recieve the XML output from process.php to jquery and iterate through the records. It seems like I am recieving the XML (I can see it in the debugger), but the jquery loop does not pick up the tags.

It works if I use a dummy XML directly, but that has each node closed in the same manner as HTML tags. Can I solve this by changing the PHP or using some Jquery formatting function?

**JS and PHP**

```js
$( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();
 
 $.post( "process.php","xml", function( data ) {
   
   $(data).find('post').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    var $post = $(this);
    var Msg = $post.find('Msg').text();;
    var html = '<tr><td class="bold">' + Msg + '</td></tr>';
    $( "#result" ).empty().append($(html));
   });

 });
});
```

```html
header("Content-type: text/xml");
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $node = $dom->createElement("post");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Timestamp", date("Y-m-d G:i:s",strtotime($row['TimeStamp'])));
  $newnode->setAttribute("User", $row['UserName']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("Msg", $row['Msg']);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

**Actual XML output**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<posts>
<post Msg="Heisann" User="1" Timestamp="2015-24-05 22:08:42"/>
<post Msg="Heisann" User="1" Timestamp="2015-02-06 21:10:40"/>
<post Msg="" User="1" Timestamp="2015-02-06 21:57:42"/>
```

**Dummy XML (ignore contents, just look at formatting)**

```js
 var xml = "<shows><show><date>9/8</date><place>Toads Place</place><location>New Haven, CT</location><time>9PM</time></show></shows>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first of all make a parse XML on the data received

```
xmlDataObj = $($.parseXML (data));
```

and then

```
xmlDataObj.find('post').each(function() {
   .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it still can't find "post", but if I run process.php the following is returned: <?xml version="1.0"?>

-<posts>

<post Msg="Heisann" User="1" Timestamp="2015-24-05 22:08:42"/>

Comment: Just a minor in your actual XML output in the second line i see : `-<post>` it's a typo o is not well formatted tag?

Comment: It is a minus in IE when I run the PHP file, I can press it and it minimizes the xml output. I guess it is some IE functionality, so I probably shouldn't have included it in my question.

Comment: Chek if the content of `data` is like expected. if is a valid XML must find the post